# Как переместить выпадающее меню в левый угол?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как выпадающее меню сделать в начале меню, а не напротив своего родителя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/kyzjkb1u/)

```css
#nav7,
#nav7 ul,
#nav7 li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav7,
#nav7 ul {
  background: rgb(46, 95, 122);
}
#nav7 {
  /* подменю перемещается относительно меню */
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#nav7 ul {
  /* подменю находится вне потока */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
}
#nav7 li:hover ul {
  /* подменю будет показано, если курсор наведён на пункт меню с выпадающем списком */
  display: block;
}
#nav7 li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav7 ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
#nav7 .right {
  /* последнее подменю будет расширяться справа налево */
  direction: rtl;
}
#nav7 .right ul {
  /* для IE, решение найдено случайно, где связь ??? */
  right: 0;
}
#nav7 .right li {
  /* последнее подменю будет расширяться справа налево, но не пункты последнего подменю */
  direction: ltr;
}
#nav7 a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav7 ul a {
  padding: 3px 15px;
}
#nav7 li:hover {
  background: rgb(96, 145, 172);
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav7">
  <li><a href="#1">Пункт 1</a>
    <li><a href="#2">Пункт 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#2-1">Подменю 1</a>
          <li><a href="#2-2">Подменю 2</a>
            <li><a href="#2-3">Подменю 3</a>
              <li><a href="#2-4">Подменю 4</a>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#3">Пункт 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#3-1">Подменю 1</a>
            <li><a href="#3-2">Подменю 2</a>
        </ul>
        <li class="right"><a href="#4">Пункт 4</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#4-1">Подменю 1</a>
              <li><a href="#4-2">Подменю 2</a>
                <li><a href="#4-3">Подменю 3</a>
          </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: добавьте весь необходимый код: разметку и стили непосредственно в вопрос

Comment: добавьте `#nav7 ul { left:0; }` - вот так, что-ли?

Comment: Да, благодарю!.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить задержку для развертывания? Например разворачивать меню после 2 сек. наведения курсором.

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо второму списку `ul`, который формирует выпадающий контент, добавить свойство `left:0;` - оно прижмёт выпадающий список к левому краю.

---

В вашем случае необходимо добавить следующий код: `#nav7 ul { left:0; }`